# How can i put the logo of my website on the upper-left corner in html and css?

Tags: html, css

Good evening to everybody.
I am building a website for a project from a html and css template.
Now, I have to do some changes.

I just would like to put the logo of the "enterprise" in the header, on the upper-left corner, but i cannot achieve this homework.

this is the code:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation">
            <div class="container">
            
                <div class = "navbar-logo">
                    <a href = "#" ><img src = "assets\img\logo.png"> </a>
                </div>              


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="agency-navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Home</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Servizi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contatti</b></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>   
        </nav><!-- /.site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- /#mastheaed -->
```

Comment: If you got this as homework, then the class would have previously taught you how to do this. Review the material, ask your instructor or fellow students.

Comment: This is not an homework. It is supposed to be a small project for a course, where HTML and CSS are not taught.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .container {
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .navbar-logo {
        margin-left: 10px;
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        margin-right: 10px;
        float: right;
    }

    .navbar-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;` attribute to your logo class

```
.navbar-logo {        
        float: left;
    }
```

```css
   .container {
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .navbar-logo {        
        float: left;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        float: right;
    }

    .navbar-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation">
            <div class="container">
            
                <div class = "navbar-logo">
                    <a href = "#" ><img src = "assets\img\logo.png"> </a>
                </div>              


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="agency-navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Home</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Servizi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contatti</b></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>   
        </nav><!-- /.site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- /#mastheaed -->
```